# Oracle stored procedure returns incorrect value during Hibernate test Transaction

Tags: oracle, hibernate, stored-procedures, transactions, junit4

I have a test class that extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests and uses Transactions for Integration Tests. One of the tested methods calls a Stored Procedure from an Oracle Database using Hibernate, using a named query.

The stored procedure updates the value for a column in one of the rows (by default, STATUS is "0"), then commits, and then returns the same updated value:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE TEST_PROCEDURE(
    p_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
    p_id IN NUMBER)
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE TABLE_SMPL
    SET STATUS = '1'
    WHERE REQUEST_ID IN 
       (SELECT TESTVAR.REQUEST_ID 
        FROM
         (SELECT REQUEST_ID  
            FROM TABLE_SMPL
            WHERE ID = p_id )  TESTVAR);
    commit;

    OPEN p_cursor FOR
      SELECT REQUEST_ID  
                FROM TABLE_SMPL
                WHERE ID = p_id AND STATUS = '1';

END TEST_PROCEDURE;
```

The test fails. Debugging I see that the Stored Procedure is called, and the value in the database is updated. But the returned value of the Store Procedure is the row without the value updated (the returned row has STATUS = 0).

If I call this Stored Procedure in SQL Developer, it works correctly. It updates the value, and returns the correct updated row.

If I use Hibernate statements in the method instead of the Stored Procedure, it also works correctly.

Why is the stored procedure not returning the correct value just in my Java method?

Thanks and regards.

**Edit**

One weird think I see is that I get different results when debugging than when running the test: Running it normally returns 0 results, but in debug mode it returns one result, with the un-updated values.

**Edit 2**

Nevermind, the difference in results when running it normally and in debug mode were caused because I introduced another condition in the SELECT that was failing.

Comment: What is the transaction isolation level?  Any chance you've set it to serializable in your Java code?

Comment: I've changed the isolation level to READ_COMMITTED and still it doesn't return the updated row. It seems like the commit in the middle of the stored procedure is not working.

Comment: If you are in read committed mode, the commit in the middle doesn't do anything.  Your cursor would see the uncommitted changes that you had made in the current session.  How are you seeing that "the returned row has STATUS = 0" when your `SELECT` statement does not return the `status` column?  What you're describing does not make sense.  It's possible, of course, that you've stumbled upon a horrible bug in Oracle that is based on some incredibly unique setup you have.  But it's far more likely that there is a mistake in your description or in the calling code.

Comment: Sorry, the return SELECT was using * instead of just bringing one column. Still, the problem persists (with, and without the commit in the middle).